# Как подружить twitter bootstrap и tinymce?

Tags: веб-программирование, bootstrap, tinymce, php, yii

Привет!

Как подружить twitter bootstrap и tinymce?

Проект на yii, использую расширения Yii-Bootstrap, версия 2.1.0; ETinyMce 2.0.

Если на странице осуществляется редактирование текста через tinymce, то нельзя раскрыть dropdown меню.
Если убираю со страницы tinymce, то все ок.

При нажатии на ссылку, по которой должно открываться меню, получаю ошибку в консоли:

> Failed to load resource:
> net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Comment: @Alar, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен. Установил расширение Yiistrap + расширение TinyMce заменил на newtinymce. Не уверен, что в первом 3-й бутстрап, тем не менее все заработало!!!

Comment: Надо не уходить от проблемы, а искать её решение. )

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день.

Погуглил информацию по вашему вопросу.

Пишут, что надо использовать bootstrap 3, и тогда всё хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу ошибки в консоли `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS` - у меня она встречается исключительно в Chrome и почти на всех сайтах.

В баг трекере хрома есть [issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=424599)